# Ionic nav-bar issue

Tags: ionic-framework

I am new to ionic framework

After i login to the app, i am redirecting to instance page.
In the instance page, i have a nav-bar enabled.
But i see nav-back button enabled and on refresh , i get back the nav-bar.

I tried adding 
1 hide-nav-bar = false in instance page (no use)
2 hide-back-button= true in instane page (no use)
3 In the login controller, i tried adding 
             $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
                      disableBack: true
                    });
   before i have 
   $state.go('instance');                (no use)

But when i refresh, from then on, it works fine.
Can someone help on this

Comment: So what exactly you want? you want to hide backbutton?

Comment: Exactly.  I want to hide back button.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [$ionicNavBarDelegate](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicNavBarDelegate/)

In your controller

```
.controller('YourCtrl', function($ionicNavBarDelegate) {
     $ionicNavBarDelegate.showBackButton(false);
 })
```